# Error when creating an element type COMBIN14 using pymapdl

Tags: python, ansys, ansys-apdl, pyansys

I'm trying to create a mass-spring system attached to a plate with element type `COMBIN14` for the spring and `MASS21` for the mass.
I have created the nodes needed to attach the mass and the spring. I have used this command to create the element type `COMBIN14`:

```py
mapdl.et(2)
mapdl.real(2)

for j in range(1, 10):
    mapdl.e(node_number_i[j-1], node_number_j[j-1])
```

But when i run this command i am getting the following error:

```
*** ERROR *** CP = 15.156 TIME= 11:38:07
Element 1001 does not have all of its required nodes defined. The E
command is aborted.
*** ERROR
```

Could anyone tell me what is the problem here?

I have checked the vectors, `node_number_i` and `node_number_j`, the node number listed are valid and correct.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you selected the wrong element type for creating COMBIN14 elements with two nodes. I was able to reproduce this problem by using the following code:

```
...
/PREP7
N,1,0,0,0       ! create two nodes
N,2,1,0,0
ET,1,SHELL181   ! define element type 181, which needs 4 nodes
ET,2,COMBIN14   ! define spring element, which needs 2 nodes
E,1,2           ! results in an error, because 4 nodes are needed
...
```

To resolve this problem make sure that you have selected the proper element type by using `TYPE` (in my example use `TYPE,2`). In PyANSYS the command looks like `Mapdl.type(2)`. Here is the working code:

```
...
/PREP7
N,1,0,0,0       ! create two nodes
N,2,1,0,0
ET,1,SHELL181   ! define element type 181, which needs 4 nodes
ET,2,COMBIN14   ! define spring element, which needs 2 nodes
TYPE,2
E,1,2           ! create spring element
...
```

Just rewrite it to PyANSYS and it should work properly.